# Camera access and photo gallery together Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-camera

According to a **Ionic 3** project I would like to get access from a click  button to the camera native device in the background and the gallery together in the same screen. I saw on the web many topics where we could get a modal asking you the choice between both  like this one [Ionic 2 Camera tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-images/) but I would like to get get **the gallery from photoAlbum covering (similar to a footer) the Camera (section like) as a background** a bit like a whatsapp/facebook messenger api when you press the camera logo...is that possible in Ionic 3? Maybe using two different pages and calling them together ? (I am actually trying that way)

Since Ionic version 3 is there a way to make it natively or if anyone got ideas about js/css way to make it :-) ..thanks in advance

Here is my fonctional code only with the camera:

home.html:

```
   <button class="charlotte-button" color="gray" ion-button icon-left 
  (click)="takePhoto()">
          <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
          Take a photo
        </button>
```

home.ts:

```
 export Class HomePage {
 myphoto: any;
 }
  constructor(privae camera: Camera) {}
   takePhoto() {
   const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 70,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    };

this.camera.getPicture().then(
  imageData => {
    // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
    this.imageURL = imageData;
    // If it's base64:
    this.myphoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  },
  err => {
    // Handle error
  }
);
 }
```